# Streaming video from webcam through network with C++ application

Tags: c++, opencv, networking

I want to create *server and client applications* for controlling electronic device through network.

**Server application** should stream video from web camera (RGB, 320 * 240) with some information about current state of device and control microcontroller device via RS-232.

**Client application** should allow to adjust controlling process and show video from web camera and some information about device.

**What i have done:** I use Qt framework in oder to create GUI of both applications and TCP sockets, also I use OpenCV to get images from camera. Server application compresses images in JPEG, add some information about device (~ 60 bytes) and send to client.

**Problem:** In Local network everything works fine, but working through Internet I can get only about 15 fps because JPEG images are too large. With stronger JPEG compression I can get suitable fps, but with bad image quality. So I wonder is there any better ways to stream video with some extra information about current state of device? Maybe with FFMPEG or something else.

Thanks for your replies and sorry for my english!

Comment: I think, something similar to gstreamer could help you, just check about gstreamer.

Comment: Thank you, I will read about it

Comment: Hi sir! How did you solve the problem, I also have the same question. Thanks!